# Waschkorb um 180° nestbar

Tags: meaning

Ich habe in einer Werbung für Waschkörbe gelesen: "Waschkörbe um 180° nestbar".

Was heißt nestbar? Im Duden steht es nicht: http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/nestbar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Befragt man eine Suchmaschine nach dem Begriff, so erkennt man, dass es sich dabei um

> Drehstapelbehälter

handelt. Das sind Behälter, die so konstruiert sind, dass sie in einer Richtung ineinander gestapelt werden können. Dreht man sie aber um 180 °, so können sie aufeinander gestapelt werden.

Das heißt wenn die Behälter gefüllt sind, können sie übereinander gestapelt werden. Sind sie leer, können sie hingegen platzsparend ineinander gestellt werden.

Comment: Ich hab leider nur "The Nest Bar" in New York gefunden :)

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Recherche, ich frage mich aber schon, was du da gefunden hast, ist es wirklich ein deutsches Wort oder grauenhaftes Denglisch?

Comment: Zum Beispiel [Suchergebnis1](https://www.aldi-sued.de/de/angebote/angebote-ab-donnerstag-22-juni/detailseite-kw23-do220617/ps/p/easy-home-koerbe-set-stapelbar-220617/) oder [Suchergebnis2](https://www.transoplast.de/produkte/kunststoffbehalter/stapel-nestbarer-behalter-euronorm---600-x-400-x-h-180-mm-4128760--farbnummer.aspx). Beides Mal findet sich auf den Seiten dieser seltsame Begriff "nestbar". Ich persönlich halte es nicht für ein deutsches Wort, sondern auch für denglisch.

Comment: Ich halte es vor allem für ein Marketingwort

Comment: Es gibt seit 5 Jahren einen Wikipedia [ https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nestbarer_Beh%C3%A4lter ], darüber hinaus wird es als Fachbegriff erklärt: [ https://www.transpack-krumbach.de/it/unternehmen/glossar/m-n-o/nestbar ]
Wohl doch nicht so neu.

Comment: Ein Wikipedia-Eintrag ist noch keine Garantie für Richtigkeit. Selbst mit der Definition erzeugt die Formulierung "um 180° nestbar" reichlich Bauchschmerzen.

Answer (score 10):

Wahrscheinlich ist das wieder mal [Denglisch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denglisch), weil die Hersteller glauben, dass die Kunden es mögen, wenn möglichst viele Fremdwörter verwendet werden.

Im Englischen hätte "*to nest*" unter anderem die Bedeutung: "*ineinander stecken*".

Comment: Ein Kandidat für die Liste der grauenhaften Werbewörter.

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nestbarer_Beh%C3%A4lter

Comment: Ich würde *stapelbar* dazu sagen. Und wenn es unbedingt auf den Unterschied zwischen *aufeinanderstapelbar* und *ineinanderstapelbar* ankommt, dann - bittesehr.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Du verkennst den unschlagbaren Vorteil von Denglisch: Wenn der Supermarkt den Korb als "stapelbar" verkauft und das Ding geht kaputt, weil es eben doch nicht stapelbar ist, ist das ein Garantiefall. Wenn er den Korb als "nestbar" bewirbt, kann er immer noch behaupten, dass mit dem Wort "nestbar" was ganz anderes gemeint ist... :-)